# ASP.NET MVC 5 consumiendo apiweb

Tags: asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, api, asp

Estoy consumiendo una api la cual me devuelve como response lo siguiente:

```
{
    "rows": {
        "recordset": [
            {
                "Monto": "10000000",
                "CantidadDias": 50,
                "TasaDiaria": "0.009700000000000",
                "TasaPeriodo": "0.48",
                "MontoInteres": 48000,
                "MontoFinal": 10048000
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como consumir esos datos, partiendo por el modelo para luego consumirlos en el controller.

Mi controller: (Es un Metodo que esta en el controller)

```
private static async Task<object> NewMethod(object RootObject, HttpClient client)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:0000/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("authentication");

        try
        {
            var department = new Rows { recordset = new List<Recordset>() };
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/simuladorDAP", department);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var EmpResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Recordset>(EmpResponse);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw (e);
        }

        return RootObject;
    }
```

Para hacer el post se deben pasar 2 parametros, es aca donde nose como llenar la lista que tengo en esta linea para pasarle esos dos parametros.

Los parametros son Monto y CantidadDias.

> var department = new Rows { recordset = new List() };

Mi modelo:

```
public class Recordset
{
    public string Monto { get; set; }
    public int CantidadDias { get; set; }
    public string TasaDiaria { get; set; }
    public string TasaPeriodo { get; set; }
    public int MontoInteres { get; set; }
    public int MontoFinal { get; set; }
}

public class Rows
{
    public List<Recordset> recordset { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Rows rows { get; set; }
}
```

Me podrían indicar como lo debería hacer por favor o bien en que me estoy equivocando. Gracias.

Comment: Hmm..no termino de entenderte. En tu código hay un error en esta linea:`RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Recordset>(EmpResponse);`.Es ahi donte te falla? te da algun error de compilacion?

Comment: No, el error lo tengo en esta linea var department = new Rows { recordset = new List() }; de hecho no es un error ya que no eh ejecutado la aplicacion, el problema es que nose como llenar esa lista para pasarle los parametros CantidadDias y Monto (del modelo) al  PostAsJsonAsync()

Comment: Te refieres a hacer esto? `var department = new Rows { recordset = new List<Recordset>() { new Recordset() { Monto = "10", CantidadDias = 20 } } };`

Comment: Eso mismo ! pero lo probé y aun así no me devuelve los datos, me devuelve un 401, tal vez algo mas tengo mal con los modelos.

Comment: Creo que tienes varios problemas. Te he puesto una respuesta, fijate sobre todo en la ultima parte. Entiendo que debes enviar un json al api para que te responda, como se explica en la respuesta. De todas maneras, si no es asi, debes pulsar en [edit] y añadir mas información sobre el api, que datos de entrada espera y que datos de salida responde.

Answer (score 0):

Para inicializar una lista en linea (*inline initialization*), en este caso un `List<Recordset>`, lo primero a tener en cuenta es indicar específicamente el tipo de la lista (`Recordset` en este caso). Luego, se crean los nuevos objetos del tipo correcto, y estos pueden inicializarse en linea con los parámetros necesarios.

Resumiendo, de tu pregunta se deduce que quieres crear un objeto de tipo `Rows` e inicializar los parámetros `Monto` y `CantidadDias` (entiendo que de la primera fila). Esto se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
var department = new Rows { recordset = new List<Recordset>() { new Recordset() { Monto = "10", CantidadDias = 20 } } };
```

Aunque en realidad imagino que lo que quieres es crear un objeto de ripo `RootObject`, para serializarlo y enviarlo a la api. Con lo que en realidad sería algo asi:

```
var department = new Rootobject() { rows = new Rows { recordset = new List<Recordset>() { new Recordset() { Monto = "10", CantidadDias = 20 } } } };
var jsondepartment = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(department);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/simuladorDAP", jsondepartment);
```